.predict() gives me warning
I made an basic multiple linear regression model and ı wanted predict some values but ı
took this warning
array=np.array([[26,1.5],[27,3]])
multiple_linear_regression.predict(array)


/Users/mali/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:464: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but LinearRegression was fitted with feature names
  warnings.warn(
array([31926.2169    , 35070.62783243])

but code is worked but ı wondered what is that warning and how can ı fixed it?
